# Write a json text

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-7

I'm using lkJSON-1.07 in delphi 7, in their example

```
js := TlkJSONobject.Create;
js.Add('namestring','namevalue');
// get the text of object
s := TlkJSON.GenerateText(js);
  writeln(s);
writeln;
writeln('more readable variant:');
// (ver 1.03+) generate readable text
i := 0;
s := GenerateReadableText(js,i);
writeln(s);

js.Free;
```

it generate a text like this:
{
  "namestring":"namevalue"
}

How do I write a json text format like this one:

```json
{
  "Users": 
  {
    "test_user1":
    {
        "time":1600,
        "Points":4
    }
    "test_user2":
    {
        "time":1500,
        "Points":3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want different in yours? Is it the nested dictionaries? Also, you don't have a comma after `"test_user1": { ... }` which you'll likely need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using the [JSON Delphi Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/) you have to adopt the method which follows in order to add child JSON elements to their parents:

```
function TlkJSONobject.Add(const aname: WideString; aobj: TlkJSONbase): Integer;
```

The method allows the `aobj` parameter to be attached as a child of an `aname` element.

The code below allows to accomplish your task:

```
var
  js0, js1, js2, js22: TlkJSONobject;
  s: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  js2 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
  js2.Add('time', '1600');
  js2.Add('Points', 4);

  js22 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
  js22.Add('time', '1500');
  js22.Add('Points', 3);

  js1 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
  js1.Add('test_user1', js2);          
  js1.Add('test_user2', js22);

  js0 := TlkJSONobject.Create;
  js0.Add('Users', js1);

  i := 0;
  s := GenerateReadableText(js0, i);
  WriteLn(s);

  js0.Free;
end;
```

---

This is a more suitable way to write the previous code - but less readable in my opinion.

The idea here is to create the elements in the natural parent-child relationship order: the children are added to the already inserted parent using the `Field` property of the `TlkJSONobject` object.

Please notice that `js.Field['some string']` is the same as `js['some string']` because of the `default` directive applied to the `Field` property.

```
var
  js: TlkJSONobject;
  s: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  js := TlkJSONobject.Create;
  try
    js.Add('Users', TlkJSONobject.Create);

    with TlkJSONobject(js['Users']) do begin
      Add('test_user1', TlkJSONobject.Create);
      Add('test_user2', TlkJSONobject.Create);
    end;

    with TlkJSONobject(TlkJSONobject(js['Users'])['test_user1']) do begin
      Add('time', '1600');
      Add('Points', 4);
    end;

    with TlkJSONobject(TlkJSONobject(js['Users'])['test_user2']) do begin
      Add('time', '1500');
      Add('Points', 3);
    end;

    i := 0;
    s := GenerateReadableText(js, i);
    WriteLn(s);

  finally
    js.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

Running the project, it prints:

```json
{
     "Users":{
         "test_user1":{
             "time":"1600",
             "Points":4
         },
         "test_user2":{
             "time":"1500",
             "Points":3
         }
     }
}
```

---

In a real case, you obviously will consider to create the objects and append the children using some loop instruction.